# Netbeans' font looks funny after upgrading JDK from 6 to 7

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

After upgrading JDK from 1.6.0_24 to 1.7.0, the font in Netbeans (on Windows 7) editor looks funny. I did not change any configuration on Netbeans except changing the JDK_HOME to jdk1.7.0 folder. How to get the old font back?

Edit:
I use monospaced and it points to Courier New for both JDK version. (The `jre/lib/fontconfig.properties.src` files in both jdk1.6.0_24 and jdk1.7.0 folder show
`monospaced.plain.alphabetic=Courier New`)

Comment: It may actually be a huge bug you were experiencing, still around after all this time: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=216655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to figure out what your old default font (googling maybe? or just find a font you like...  I suggest Consolas if you have that font installed) was and go to Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors and st the font (on the Syntax tab).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Consolas does look much better than Courier New! Didn't know this great font.

Comment: Glad to help!  Someone suggested Consolas to me a while back, and I've changed my font on basically everything to it :).